# CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. in android after update gradle and gradle plugin

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, retrofit2, gradle-plugin

I try to check SSL, by this code (and work successfully):

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
        .add("example.com", "sha256/S4AbJNGvyS57nzJwv8sPMUML8VHSqH1vbiBftdPcErI=")
        .build();
OkHttpClient client1 = httpBuilder
        .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
        .build();
Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client1)
        .baseUrl("https://example.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
samaniumRestApi2 userClient = retrofit1.create(samaniumRestApi2.class);
Call<Object> call = userClient.maintenanceMode(requestmaintenanceModeCheck);
call.enqueue(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);
```

and I get error by change base url to:

```
https://example.com:448/
```

or

```
https://subdomain.example.com/
```

and error is :

```
CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

please save me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would mean that certificate is issued for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) ,  and thus  can not be trusted for whatever.example.com   -  this server need proper signed  certificate